# Switching users of same group in linux

Tags: linux, file-transfer, su

My environment is like:

I have two users 'user1' and 'user2' both are in same group (say group name is 'abc') in server 'server1'. Now I have another server 'server2' which have user 'user2'. User2 in both the servers are exchanged their public keys (I mean to say authentication configured properly).

Now my requirement is like:

I have to perform a copy operation on server2 (both source and destination folders are in server2 only) from server1 as user2(because identity file configuration done successfully as said above), but currently I have loggedin as user1, user1 doesn't have permissions to use 'su' to switch to user2 (not only user1 all users belongs 'abc' group are don't have permission to use 'su').

1. How can I perform copy operation on server2 without using su (or any other command like su, my expectation is from boot files)?

Answer (score 0):

Just tell SSH to use "user2" when connecting to the 2nd server:

```
ssh user2@server2

ssh -l user2 server2

scp -r user2@server2:/oldpath user2@server2:/newpath
```

Comment: thanks for reply, but we don't have access to su, ssh, scp ,..., etc. for user1. Commands only have access are :  'cd', 'dir', 'ls', 'sh', 'clear', 'more', 'pwd', 'll', 'grep', 'find', 'sed', 'awk', 'date', 'tail', 'ps' .

Comment: Well, bad news, none of those commands have a "magically switch user" feature. You _could_, however, 'borrow' user1's SSH private key from ~/.ssh/id_rsa and use it to log in as user2@server2 from a less restricted system.

Comment: you mean to say like :   ssh -i /home/user1/.ssh/id_rsa user2@server2

Comment: friend, can you please elobrate your comment

It doesn't have .ssh folder in root(/)